# Projective Linear Group and Projective Space

Tags: terminology, projective-space

*my aim :* Why $GL(V)/Z(GL(V))$ is termed as *projective general linear group*?

The reason seen in books says *This group acts on the projective set/space faithfully*.

But, there can be many groups acting faithfully on projective space, can we call them also as *projective general linear group*?

I confused, and not understood the reasonings. I faced many questions from it:

Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $V^*$ denote the collection of one dimensional subspaces of $V$, it is called projective space.

For $V^*$, we can first consider its symmetric group $Symm(V^*)$- the set of all the bijections from $V^*$ to itself. If we put some structure on $V^*$, and if we look bijections preserving the structure on $V^*$, then we obtain a subgroup of $Symm(V^*)$

**Question 1.** What stuctural properties on $V^*$ the group $GL(V)/Z(GL(V))$ preserves?

**question 2.** Can we say that, $GL(V)/Z(GL(V))$ is **precisely** the set of all bijections from $V^*$ to itself which preserve certain structure on $V^*$?

**Question 3.** Is there some notion like **Projective group**  associated to $V^*$ instead of **Projective Linear Group**? If yes, how that group differs from $GL(V)/Z(GL(V))$?

**Question 4.** Since passing from $V$ to $V^*$, we have lost linearity: $V^*$ is not a vector (linear) space. Then what the term *linear* refers to in *Projective Linear Group*?

[Please point out, if questions are not clear.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V^*$ has been traditionally used to denote the dual vector space.  Let us use P$(V)$ for the projective space of 1-dimenaional subspaces of $V$.

$GL(V)$ definitely acts on P$(V)$. The subgroup of scalars, its centre, acts trivially. That is, it fixes every element of P$(V)$. (If you work with a basis the whole diagonal subgroup of $GL(n)$ acts trivially, but that subgroup is not normal).

Therefore the quotient group $PGL(V)$ acts on P$(V)$.

Comment: A subgroup of $GL(V)$ modulo scalars also acts on $P(V)$; why **that subgroup** is not called as *Projective general linear group*?

Comment: For the same reason the  set of cyclic permutations of a set  is not called the symmetric group on the set: we want to include *all* .

Answer (score 1):

I will refer to the projective space as $\mathrm{PG}(V)$ and not $V^{*}$, since $V^{*}$ usually has a different meaning.

The projective space $\mathrm{PG}(V)$ has an underlying vector space structure, so $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ acts naturally on it; however this action is not faithful, since scalar multiples of the identity matrix all induce the identity map on $\mathrm{PG}(V)$.  So by modding out by the center we **make** a group that acts faithfully. It is called the *projective general linear group* because it (faithfully) represents the action of the general linear group on the projective space.

The group preserving the structure of $\mathrm{PG}(V)$ is called the *collineation group*. For a projective space of the form $\mathrm{PG}(V)$ (where $V$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$), the full collineation group is $\mathrm{PGL}(V) \rtimes \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F})$.  Notice that $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F})$ cannot be represented as an $\mathbb{F}$-linear map on $V$.  This is sometimes called the *projective semilinear group*.

All elements of the collineation group preserve **all** subspaces of $V$.  There are some differences between linear collineations and semilinear collineations.  The linear maps are what are called *homographies*.  These are typically defined in terms of maps known as *central collineations*.  In particular, every *homography* is a product of a finite number of *central collineations*.

**Central collineation:** A map $\mu : \mathrm{PG}(V) \to \mathrm{PG}(V)$ is called a central collineation if there is some hyperplane $H$ fixed by $\mu$ (that is, $\mu$ restricted to the hyperplane acts as the identity map) called the *axis*, and a point $O$ (a point in a projective geometry is a one-dimensional subspace of the vector space) which is fixed *linewise* by $\mu$ (that is, each line through $O$ is stabilized by $\mu$).